# Get CommonsRequestLoggingFilter content in Java code

Tags: java, spring, spring-rest, spring-logback, spring-filter

I want to implement CommonsRequestLoggingFilter into my application and get the request and response into Java code:

```
@Bean
public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter() {
    CommonsRequestLoggingFilter loggingFilter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    loggingFilter.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
    loggingFilter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
    loggingFilter.setIncludePayload(true);
    loggingFilter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
    return loggingFilter;
}
```

How I can get the payload into the Rest controller code? Example:

```
@RestController
public class LoggingDemoController {

    @GetMapping("/demo/greeting")
    public String sayHello(){

        // Get here the payload from CommonsRequestLoggingFilter

        return "Hello Stranger !!!";
    }
}
```

It this somehow possible?

Comment: Have you marked @Configuration for CommonsRequestLoggingFilter  bean class ? Also, this logging filter requires the log level in your application.properties. If you are using logback.xml then i.e. <logger name="org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
</logger>

Comment: No, I haven't added @Configuration for CommonsRequestLoggingFilter bean class. Can you show me how to get the payload into the rest controller method?

Comment: Are you developing Spring web application or Springboot ?

Comment: I'm developing Spring Boot application - latest version

Answer (score -2):

Spring Boot application can be configured by adding a bean definition to enable request logging:

```
@Configuration
public class RequestLoggingFilterConfig {

    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter
          = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        filter.setIncludePayload(true);
        filter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
        filter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
        filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("REQUEST DATA : ");
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Also, this logging filter requires the log level be set to DEBUG

```
<logger name="org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
</logger>
```

Comment: Ok but the payload will be printed into server log file. How I can get the payload into my rest api method?

Comment: i didn't understand about  payload into my rest api method ?

Comment: As far as I can see CommonsRequestLoggingFilter prints messages into apache server log for example. How I can print  the messages into the Java code?